# How to have dynamic include in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm having a set of html codes present in different blade file in view, I'm trying to add these with `foreach` loop, but blade template is not able to concatenate the files following is my code:

```
@foreach($getplugin as $renderer)

    @include('themes.'$template->theme->name'.Plugins.'$plugins->find($renderer)->type'.'$plugins->find($renderer)->id)

@endforeach
```

I'm getting following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$template' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' (View: C:\wamp\www\NitsEditor\resources\views\nitseditor\test.blade.php)

Please help out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate strings and forgetting to add dots for the concatenation.

Instead of `'themes.'$template` it should be `'themes.'.$template`, and so on. You seem to be missing all of them.

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, while doing so as suggested by you, I'm getting an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.Plugins.''`, this is the folder where all the views are stored. I placed `.` in front of every `.$template`, `.$plugins`

Comment: You need to place around them, not just in front. Please google php concatenation, you really need to understand what it is.